# How can I use svn for version control if I'm going to deploy my meteor app as node.js?

Tags: node.js, svn, meteor

Hey guys I don't have any experience with setting up svn or anything, only with using it in an already set up environment. I want to deploy my meteorjs app as a node.js app on a vps I have. I have it configured with nvm and everything, but as far as I understand it, I need to use a meteor command to package my app into a node.js application. This is then able to be run with nvm and forever. But since there is this added step, does that mean I need to upload all of the code to the server, and every time someone commits changes, I rebuild the app? I'm used to checking  out my changes on my computer, then checking out the changes to deploy them to my job's beta site. On that note, is there a better way to deploy my app? I don't want to depend on any outside sources, like by using meteor's deploy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Think of Meteor as source code and the packaged version as a compiled version (think of languages like Java).  It compiles into native NodeJS code that is then able to be run on a standard machine.

For the larger Meteor apps in our organisation (deployed on multiple machines and load balanced etc) we use version control on the source code, a build manager (strider) that compiles into NodeJS and then plugs into Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.  Full build management, full deployment management.

For something simple like what you're after, use something like Meteor UP (https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) which will handle building, deploying and managing on a server).  This is pretty awesome for small server clusters.